Secrets and Certificate Expiry with Graph Powershell
So, hope someone can help me across the finish line with this. I've cobbled together a bit of code, basically something I got from a much smarter forum user for a similar purpose.
I'm trying to take all the App Registrations and their secrets/certificate expiry dates and put that information into a PSCustomObject.
This is the bit of code that does the work
# Loop through all apps and add to PSCustomObject
$uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$select=displayName, passwordCredentials, id'
 
$result = do {
    $Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $Headers
    $uri = $Data.'@odata.nextLink'
 
    foreach ($app in $Data.value) {
 
        $appUri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$select=displayName, passwordCredentials, id'
        $allAppSecretsExpiry = do {
            $cred = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $appUri -Headers $Headers
            $appUri = $cred.'@odata.nextLink'
            if ($cred) {
                $cred.value.passwordCredentials.endDateTime
            }
        }
        while ($appUri)
 
        [pscustomobject]@{
            displayName = $app.displayName
            id          = $app.id
            Credentials = $allAppSecretsExpiry
        }
    }
}
while ($uri)

Then, what I get is a list of all apps and their ID, but the property for expiration date, I get all expiry dates for all apps, something like this
APP1      {2025-05-15 17:55:57, 2024-08-13 08:55:07, 2026-04-15 09:06:50, 202… 
APP2      {2025-05-15 17:55:57, 2024-08-13 08:55:07, 2026-04-15 09:06:50, 202… 
APP3      {2025-05-15 17:55:57, 2024-08-13 08:55:07, 2026-04-15 09:06:50, 202…
APP4      {2025-05-15 17:55:57, 2024-08-13 08:55:07, 2026-04-15 09:06:50, 202…

I'm sure I've made a mistake in the foreach loop, but I can't see where.
Hopefully some kind soul can help me out and I'll learn something along the way.

you can take a look this site about PScustumObject https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.4

service principals can have many secrets, you're missing an inner loop on $cred.value.passwordCredentials for each secret basically create a new object. this might help: https://gist.github.com/santisq/3006911d2f99c16ba071fdbadbac66e2#file-appreport-ps1

@SantiagoSquarzon thanks for posting that link, it looks quite interesting and looks to be a better version of what I'm trying to do, although I'm getting an error when running it against my environment.
Cannot convert argument "app", with value: "@{appId=4a29eb17-0f49-44ca-8140-XXXXXXXXXX; id=XXXXXXXX-4ee7-4625-9ac5-9feac574ad4b; displayName=<REDACTED>;  .................. "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".""
Don't suppose it's something you've seen before.

@thekevinkalis so that error makes me think you are not using Invoke-MgGraphRequest and are using Invoke-RestMethod instead because the Mg cmdlet outputs hashtables as its default output and Invoke-RestMethod converts the Json response to a PSCustomObject. The usage of Invoke-MgGraphRequest is important in this code.

@SantiagoSquarzon I find it mindblowing that you could tell that just by the error message. I try to user "Invoke-RestMethod" as far as possible, but am obviously still learning the quirks. I don't suppose there's a quick/easy way to adjust your script so it works. It's a bit beyond my middling abilities.

added the answer tho I do recommend using Invoke-MgGraphRequest, it's really nice because you don't need to care about refreshing your token, it does that for you.

The main issue with your code is that you're missing an inner loop to go through each secret (.passwordCredentials property). Because applications can have more than one secret, you are ending up with a single object per app with all secrets as an array. Fixing the problem is fairly simple:
$invokeRestMethodSplat = @{
    Method  = 'GET'
    Uri     = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$select=displayName, passwordCredentials, id'
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = 'Bearer {myTokenGoesHere}'
    }
}

$result = do {
    $Data = Invoke-RestMethod @invokeRestMethodSplat
    $invokeRestMethodSplat['Uri'] = $Data.'@odata.nextLink'

    foreach ($app in $Data.value) {
        foreach ($secret in $app.passwordCredentials) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                displayName       = $app.displayName
                id                = $app.id
                startDateTime     = $secret.startDateTime
                endDateTime       = $secret.endDateTime
                secretDisplayName = $secret.displayName
            }
        }
    }
}
while ($invokeRestMethodSplat['Uri'])

# do stuff with `$result`
$result ...

Do note this current implementation only covers Client Secrets (clientId + secret password). If you want to also include Client Certificates you need to include keyCredentials in your $select parameter and would need to include an additional inner loop on $app.keyCredentials.

This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks. This is also the first time I've seen Invoke-RestMethod called in this way, so thanks for teaching me something new.

im glad it was helpful @thekevinkalis. do note this current implementation only covers client secrets (cliendId + secret password). if you want to also include client certificates you need to include keyCredentials in your $select and would need to include an additional inner loop on $app.keyCredentials just like in the gist I shared before. If you have further questions regarding this, feel free to ask a new question in this site

@SantiagoSquarzon what if there are multiple secrets for same app, does it show all or only one with latest expiry?

There is a loop on $app.passwordCredentials, so yes @BBJinu

Thanks I was expecting to show more values in same cell but that didn’t show as expected. It was just showing only one expiry for each app. Let me try running one more time.
